# Regex all the contents Using regex

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expression. I got the following pattern,

```
LastName, FirstName 04/12/2014

AAAA

BBBB

CCCC

LastName, FirstName 04/12/2014

DDDD

EEEE

FFFF

LastName, FirstName 04/12/2014

GGGG

HHHH
```

I want to split the above string by LastName, FirstName 04/12/2014 and its contents.
So, for the above example, I will get 3 Strings.

String 1 :

```
LastName, FirstName 04/12/2014

AAAA

BBBB

CCCC
```

String 2 :

```
LastName, FirstName 04/12/2014

DDDD

EEEE

FFFF
```

String 3 :

```
LastName, FirstName 04/12/2014

GGGG

HHHH
```

I am using the following regular expression to match the pattern,

But it is not getting the contents,

```
[a-zA-Z]*\s*\,\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}
```

Please let me know how do I split the string like above using regex.

Comment: your LastName and FirstName  are variables? or constant string?

Comment: You may wish to include code as well

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses. LastName, firstname are variables its not constants

Comment: @user2831003 what language are you using ?

Comment: I am using salesforce which has apex programming language.

Comment: @user2831003 please use `@` + name of person you're messaging to otherwise that person won't receive a notification. Let's talk about your issue. In that application, can you split instead of match ? If so, try to use `\s+(?=[^,\r\n]+,[^\r\n]+?\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})`

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you use a multiline regex. How to do this depend on the language, e.g. Appending "m" after the regex or using a multiline flag when creating the regex.
2. Your regex does not contain code for anything after the date. How to code this depends on the nature of your "contents". Make sure the code can not match the next LastName,...-line.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex

`LastName(.*?)(?=LastName|$)`

[RegexDemo](http://regex101.com/r/gC9nE6)

Comment: `LastName` is just an example. So this would fail for a generic input